# SSIS For Loop with DATEADD in assignexpression

Tags: sql-server, for-loop, ssis

I have an SSIS for loop and in the assign expression part of the for loop I need to increment with a DATEADD function but the date part needs to be dependent on my variable:

```
@DateStart = DATEADD(@TypeIncrement,@DayIncrement,@DateStart)
```

If i change it ,it will work:

```
@DateStart = DATEADD(dd,@Increment,@DateStart)
```

but if I try to do it this way its just giving me an error saying The date part parameter specified for function "DATEADD" is not valid.

I have also tried changing it to be a case statement with different date parts but that wouldn't work either. 
Any ideas?

Thanks.

----------------EDIT

a lot of ppl are posting sql server answers. but i need it working here:

[image: Ive done a quick demo. I know its hh and dd but its should still work]

Comment: `CASE @TypeIncrement` really is your friend here. What's the thing you tried that "wouldn't work"? (And presumably `@DayIncrement` is a misnomer if it can be about other things than days?)

Comment: yea i need to rename the variable. Basically its not allowing me to pass in a variable for the first parameter. Its breaking when I have the @TypeIncrement there. I've edited my answer abit to help

Comment: That's correct, which is why you'd do `CASE @TypeIncrement when 'DAY' THEN DATEADD(DAY, ...) WHEN 'MONTH' THEN ...` etcetera. The first parameter must be a literal, but you can definitely use `CASE`.

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
Declare @TypeIncrement varchar(10) = 'MM'
Declare @DayIncrement int = 5
Declare @DateStart date = '2017-03-15'

Select Case @TypeIncrement
       When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, @DayIncrement, @DateStart) 
       When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, @DayIncrement, @DateStart) 
       When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, @DayIncrement, @DateStart) 
       When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, @DayIncrement, @DateStart) 
       When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, @DayIncrement, @DateStart) 
       End
```

**Returns**

```
2017-08-15
```

Comment: this works in sql but im trying to do it inside SSIS For Loop and its still throwing an error

Comment: @Budyn Seeing double quotes in your image "dd"  should just be DD

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter doesn't accept a variable as an input. One alternate option to a `CASE` might be dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @IncrementType nvarchar(10), @Increment int, @DateStart date;
SET @IncrementType = N'DAY';
SET @Increment = 5;
SET @DateStart = GETDATE();

IF @IncrementType NOT IN (N'YEAR',N'QUARTER',N'MONTH',N'DAYOFYEAR',N'DAY',N'WEEK',N'WEEKDAY',N'HOUR',N'MINUTE',N'SECOND',N'MILLISECOND',N'MICROSECOND',N'NANOSECOND') BEGIN

    DECLARE @Error nvarchar(500) = 'Invalid input for Increment Type(''' + @IncrementType + N'''. Valid options are: YEAR, QUARTER, MONTH, DAYOFYEAR, DAY, WEEK, WEEKDAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, MILLISECOND, MICROSECOND, NANOSECOND.'
    RAISERROR(@Error,11,-1);

END ELSE BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @SQL = N'SET @dDateStart = DATEADD(' + @IncrementType + N',@dIncrement,@dDateStart)'
    PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@dDateStart date OUTPUT, @dIncrement int', @dDateStart = @DateStart OUTPUT, @dIncrement = @Increment;

END

SELECT @DateStart;
```

This might be over complicating it, but it's an alternate to the `CASE` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

implementing inside SSIS:

to get this:

```
@DateStart = DATEADD(dd,@Increment,@DateStart)
```

Try this:

```
@DateStart = @TypeIncrement=="dd" ? DATEADD(dd,@Increment,@DateStart)
             : @TypeIncrement=="mm" ? DATEADD(MM,@Increment,@DateStart)
```

and so on...

If then else is in the format of:

Test   ?    true part :    false part